# d3js error on decrementing datapoints - how to resolve?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

So, I have a series of datapoints with incrementing/decrementing counters which are graphed:

```
{id: 1, count: 1, abnormal: 0, visualisation_colour: #FFFFFF};
{id: 2, count: 2, abnormal: 0, visualisation_colour: #FFFFFF};
{id: 3, count: 3, abnormal: 0, visualisation_colour: #FFFFFF};
```

If I decrement the counters (`count`, and `abnormal`) to zero, then start incrementing them again, I get:

```
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute 
d="M0,-100A100,100 0 1,1 NaN,NaNLNaN,NaNA50,50 0 1,0 0,-50Z"
```

Which repeats for all the zero'd datapoints. How do I prevent this from occurring, as also once they have been zeroed out, incrementing them again fails too with the same error. I'm using the (now working) code referenced in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25967366/781909)

Comment: This appears to be closely related to the question at http://stackoverflow.com/q/19933581/781909

Comment: Well the answer to the question you've linked to has a workaround. Does that work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer basically encompasses [@Lars Kotthoff's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1172002/lars-kotthoff) answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19936244/781909).

By bringing in the filter he uses:

```
if(data.filter(function(d) { return d.totalCrimes > 0; }).length > 0) {
```

Into the `renderSlices` function:

```
function renderSlices(pie, arc) {
    var slices;

    if (pie(_data).filter(function(d) {return d.value > 0;}).length > 0 ) {

        slices = _pieG.selectAll("path.arc")
            .data(pie(_data));

        slices.enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("class", "arc")
            .attr("fill", function(d) {
                return d.data.visualisation_colour;
            });

        slices.transition()
            .attrTween("d", function(d) {
                var currentArc = this.__current__;
                if (!currentArc) {
                    currentArc = {startAngle: 0, endAngle: 0};
                }
                var interpolate = d3.interpolate(currentArc, d);
                this.__current__ = interpolate(1);
                return function(t) {
                    return arc(interpolate(t));
                };
            });
    } else {
        slices = _pieG.selectAll("path.arc")
            .data(pie(_data));
        slices.remove();
}
```

You can remove all the zero'd arcs, and clean up the graph.